# What if the correct answer is not the most useful one?

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked a [question about reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5161459/329637). The correct answer I think is given by rene, but tkeE2036 gave an answer that is not really answering the question, but proposing a better way to do it (in my opinion).

So I accepted tkeE2036's answer although it is not really answering the question.

How is this handled? Should I always accpet the answer that is useful for me or the one that answers the question?

Comment: That's easy, of course you should favor the better way.  Both in your work and in your answer mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accept the answer that helped you the most.

You can always award a bounty to rene's answer.

In this case I think you should also add a comment on both answers indicating why you chose to accept the answer you did. This will make it clear that you changed your implementation and that rene's answer is not incorrect.